# EF code first add model related exist childs

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I try to add new model to DB but the model have child that already exists
and i got this error:

"A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Category.ID' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Lesson.CategoryID' on the other end."

for example:

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public List<Lesson> Lessons{ get; set; }
}

public class Lesson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I think that the Category ID still 0 until the DB will generate new ID and Lesson.CategoryID filled in 0 that not exist in Categories

Save code:

```
DB.Categories.Add(obj);
DB.ChangeTracker.Entries()
       .Where(x => x.Entity is BaseModel && x.State == EntityState.Added && ((BaseModel)x.Entity).ID > 0)
                    .ToList().ForEach(x => x.State = EntityState.Unchanged);
```

Any idea how to fix that?
Thanks anyway

Comment: how can lesson (child) be unchanged, or even exists, without Category (Parent) ?

Comment: Its many to many relation. i fix that now